# Why this table join type in the sql is ALL？

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query the students whose course1 score are better than course 2. Here is my sql.

```
SELECT  sc1.score C1Score, sc2.score C2Score,s.SId ID, s.Sname Name, s.Sage Age, s.Ssex Sex
FROM sc sc1 INNER JOIN sc sc2
ON sc1.SId = sc2.SId
  AND sc1.CId = '01'
  AND  sc2.CId = '02'
  AND sc1.score > sc2.score
INNER JOIN student s
  ON s.SId = sc1.SId
;
```

And the sql explain result:
[image]
Table `student` join type is all. Why a full table scan is done when I said:`ON s.SId = sc1.SId`

DB structure:
[image: l]

Comment: Full table scan just means that MySQL is doing a brute force scan of the entire `student` table and is not using any index to do that.  A scan is necessary to figure out how to apply the join condition.  You should review how to read a MySQL execution plan.

Comment: ... run a `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` instead.  But iam pretty sure your student table is very small (around 12 records at max) that most likely why MySQL choose to fully read that student table..

Comment: *"Full table scan just means that MySQL is doing a brute force scan"* @TimBiegeleisen with all respect but *"brute force scan"* sounds a bit odd in this context as that sounds like a full scan is always a very very very bad thing for performance which is not always the case..

Answer (score 0):

If a database searches for a row with the help of an index, it follows these steps:

1. Search in the index for the row ("index seek")
2. Use the information in the index to loop up the row in the table ("lookup")

These steps are very fast for a small number of rows.  But they add up if you have to do them often.  For a query that returns all rows in a table this method degenerates into very long runtimes.

Just reading the full table ("table scan") is the opposite: it's fast for a large number of rows.  You don't have to search and you don't have to do lookups.

As a rule of thumb, when a database expects a join to require more than 100 lookups, it prefers the full table scan.